# Keycloak - How to add Back to app link on login page

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, login-page, custom-theme

I would like to know how to add a Back to App link on the keycloak login page.
I'm using a react front end, and when i use the method keycloak.login() i'm going to my keycloak server. And here i want to add the possibility to go back to my app  on the redirectUri sent by the keycloak login method.

I don't find any options in the realm management, and i have created a custom theme and i don't get the name of the properties to acces to the redirectUri link.

Thank's
Arthur

Answer (score 4):

in the `login/template.ftl` file you have access to a `client` variable. This variable is an instance of [ClientBean](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/forms/login/freemarker/model/ClientBean.java). This bean exposes a variable `baseUrl`, which you can use to link to your client application.

For Example:

```
<a href=${client.baseUrl} class="block">${kcSanitize(msg("loginTitleHtml",(realm.displayNameHtml!'')))?no_esc}</a>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, unfortunately if your client ins'nt already logged in we don't have acces to this variable

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to use my app's sign up page via a link in keycloak login page.

What I did was I set my app base url in "Base url" in my client settings. And then I was able to access it from login.ftl using "${client.baseUrl}"

Comment: I also set the Base URL for my client, but when using it with the backToApplication I am redirect to the account page of Keycloak, not to the Base URL